# AS3 Loading dynamically named text files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a preload movie that loads an interface.  In the interface I have many buttons.  When I click on a button I want to load a text file into a movie called "TextMovie.swf".  I want to be able to click on a button, take the name of the button and load a text file that is the same name as the button instance, and have the window appear close to the mouse click.  There will be hundreds of buttons and hundreds of text files.  I'm sure this is easy for some.  Here is the loader for a button:

```
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPosition_2);

function fl_ClickToPosition_2(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
var my2ndLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var url2:URLRequest = new URLRequest("TextMovie.swf");
my2ndLoader.load(url2);
addChild(my2ndLoader);
my2ndLoader.x = 200;    
my2ndLoader.y = 10;

}
```

Then in the TextMovie.swf I have:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.text.StyleSheet;

var css:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
css.setStyle("a:hover", {textDecoration:"underline"});

var textLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
textLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, textLoaded);

loadText();

function textLoaded(evt: Event): void {
title_txt.htmlText = textLoader.data.txtTitle;
main_txt.htmlText = textLoader.data.txtBody;
URL_txt.htmlText = textLoader.data.txtURL;
URL_txt.styleSheet = css
}

function loadText(): void {
// var fileName: String = "assets/test_01.txt";
var fileName: String = "assets/" +  +  ".txt";
textLoader.load(new URLRequest(fileName));
}
```

I'm not sure how to get the name of the button I pushed and apply it to the string that will load the correct text file.  I also can't get the window to appear close to the mouse click.  Right now I just have it set with an x and y for testing.

I know it's a lot but thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the docs for [MouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) so you better understand what data is passed as parameters when the event is triggered.

In the event handler, a reference is passed to the object which was clicked: the event `target`– and from that you can get its name, location, etc. This is good because it means you only need one event handler for all your buttons.

Once you have the name, you can build the string you need for your url. (I wouldn't do it that way if it is a project which is going to have any sort of lifespan but it's an ok approach).

You can get the x and y location of the `target`, its width and height, and use that data to position your window. The `localX` and `localY` properties refer to the click location relative to the rect of the `target` (button) – with top/left of the `target`== 0,0.

> **This is the trace output from the function below:**
>   red red.swf
>   600 400
>   25 8.5

---

```
  button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onHandleButtonClick);
```

---

```
        function onHandleButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            var btnName:String = event.target.name;
            var swfName:String = btnName + ".swf";

            trace(btnName, swfName);
            trace(event.target.x, event.target.y);
            trace(event.localX, event.localY);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Will!  I'll try that out.  Just curious, what approach would you use?

Comment: @GTex62 - I would separate the data from the implementation details of the GUI (how btns are named) since that is inflexible and brittle. I would instead use an `associative array`, with the button name as a key to look up what the url should be. Also externalize it into XML or JSON text file – that way I can change links by changing the text and not having to recompile the swf. See: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html